# Currency symbol not formatting correctly in a textView?

Tags: android, fonts

In my app **I have a message which can be customised by the user** and then displayed in the app.

**If the user enters "£100" it is shown as "Â£100"?**

I tried to use a font which contains this symbol but it didn't fix my problem.

```
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "arial_unicode.ttf");

alertTextView.setTypeface(font);

alertTextView.setText(message);
```

I tried to use *Arial Unicode MS, Verdana, Arial, Code2000... but the problem persits.

Any ideas?

Comment: But why you used custom font to display pound symbol??

Comment: Just used `String EURO = "\u20AC";`

Comment: Because with the default one it doesn't work.

Comment: try like `alertTextView.setText(EURO+message);`

Comment: I can't really do that because the message is set from an editText on a web site so I fetch the value from an API and I display this message.

Comment: It's just for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue.

The problem was about the way how I fetch and format this data in my message variable.

As I sais in my comment above, I fetch this information from Json data through an API. At this point, the character convertor that I was using wasn't correct I had to change it from "iso-8859-1" to "utf-8" to be able to read correctly my currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use the codes like `\u00A3` (lira) or try to change the encoding of the string like this:

```
byte[] myByteArray = message.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);
String encodedMessage = new String(myByteArray, Charsets.UTF_8);
alertTextView.setText(encodedMessage);
```